# MySQL: select specific users ids and complete limit randomly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have list of users ids like: (2,3,5) and need to select 5 users from "users" table, with high priority of users in the list and then complete the limit with "rand" users,

users table structure:

```
id     name
0      John
1      Adam
2      MM
3      Saly
4      Sara
5      Alx
6      Jak
7      Sarah
8      lynda
9      Riyan
```

I need to select 5 users with priority of specific ids:

example 1, if list of users ids = (2,3,5)
result:

```
id     name
2      MM
3      Saly
5      Alx
0      John
6      Jak
```

example 2, if list of users ids = (5,6,0,1,2)
result:

```
id     name
5      Alx
6      Jak
0      John
1      Adam
2      MM
```

thanks,

Comment: So you first want the users with a matching ID and then the other users but max. 5 users?

Comment: @JimmyT. yes exactly

Comment: Order of ID has to be preserved?

Comment: @JimmyT. no I don't care about order of ID

Comment: Could example 1 also result in `5,3,2,0,6`?

Comment: @JimmyT. no, cause list already have 5 ids, id = 3 will not selected

Comment: I meant example 1, not 2. I made a typo.

Comment: yes, example 1 can return (5,3,2,0,6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the users with matching ID first but maximum 5 users:

```
SELECT id, name FROM(
  SELECT id, name, 0 p FROM users WHERE id IN (...)
  UNION
  SELECT id, name, 1 p FROM users WHERE id NOT IN(...)
) tab
ORDER BY p
LIMIT 5;
```

The first select searches for the users with the given ids, the second for all other users.

The column `p` is used to put the users with matching id before the otehr users.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
     select * from
     (
       select id , name 
       from users where id in (2,3,5)
       union all
       (select temp.* from (select * from users where id not in (2,3,5) 
        order by rand() limit 2) temp )
      ) tab
      limit 5
      ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `users` ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

**Option 2**

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```